# Is this link written correctly?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, hyperlink, href

I wanna start of by stating the obvious.
I'm a total beginner at code writing and I've been doing it for 3 weeks tops.

I'm currently making a bootstrap website and I can't get my links right which is making me go crazy.
What's wrong with this?

```
     <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="../sidor/Navbar/Strength.html">Strength Training</a>
  </li>
```

The source of the html file is:
\sidor\Navbar\Strenght.html

As I click the link on my website it says "file not found, file has been moved or removed".

A big thank you to whom ever helps me with this!
Kind regards
Michael

Comment: Typo. The file name is spelt differently to the name used in the code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems fine and worked for me.

```
<li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="../sidor/Navbar/Strength.html">Strength Training</a> </li>
```

Comment: hmm, how strange.
I guess something else has to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The html seems to be completely fine and worked for me. Probably your path to the file that is stated in the `href`-attribute is not correct. So, check again if you spelled the folders and files **exactly** as you mention them in the `href`-attribute.

I don't know your actual environment and folder structure, but when looking at the paths that you mentioned, it seems like you swapped two letter in the filename.

> \sidor\Navbar\Streng**ht**.html
>
> ../sidor/Navbar/Streng**th**.html

If it is still not working after renaming or adjusting the path, remember that the path is case-sensetive (so check upper and lower case, too). Another common mistake is that the html-file is saved as .html.txt-file. This happens to most people on regular text-editor like the preinstalled windows-notepad.